# Does a person on probation have to legally identify themselves to police officers without reasonable articulable suspicion of a criminal offense

Tags: police, identification, new-hampshire

Is there a New Hampshire RSA regarding persons on probation having to by law identify themselves as being on probation and provide their name and identification to an officer, when stopped even if it’s only for civil infraction

Comment: Many states have this rule. I don't know if NH does and may answer if I can find time to research it.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Stop and identify statutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_and_identify_statutes). NH does have one.

Comment: @user71659 the requirement described in this question goes beyond a simple stop-and-identify requirement; it requires people who have been stopped and who are on probation to inform the officer of that fact.

Answer (score 2):

New Hampshire has published restrictions for persons on probation:  https://www.nh.gov/nhdoc/divisions/victim/pandp_offender.html

These restriction include agreeing to searches by the Probation-Parole Officer ("PPO"), but do not mention identification to a general peace officer.  New Hampshire law allows the police to request the identity of person the officer has reason to suspect is committing or may be about to commit a crime (this is less of a standard than probable cause).  Failure to identify is a crime, and a subsequent arrest would require notification of the PPO, though the requirements above state that the PPO must be notified of even mere questioning by a law enforcement officer.  The identification requirement applies to everyone.

I can find no requirement that the identification requires the person to mention that they are on probation.